# How precise is numpy's sin(x) ? How do I find out? [need it to numerically solve x=a*sin(x)]

Tags: python, numpy, precision, trigonometry, numerical-methods

I'm trying to numerically solve the equation `x=a*sin(x)`, where `a` is some constant, in python. I already tried first solving the equation symbolically, but it seems this particular shape of expression isn't implemented in sympy. I also tried using sympy.nsolve(), but it only gives me the first solution it encounters.

My plan looks something like this:

```
x=0
a=1
rje=[]
while(x<a):
    if (x-numpy.sin(x))<=error_sin:
        rje.append(x)
    x+=increment

print(rje)
```

I don't want to waste time or risk missing solutions, so I want to know how to find out how precise numpy's sinus is on my device (that would become error_sin).

edit: I tried making both error_sin and increment equal to the machine epsilon of my device but it a) takes to much time, and b) sin(x) is less precise that x and so I get a lot of non-solutions (or rather repeated solutions because sin(x) grows much slower than x). Hence the question.

edit2: Could you please just help me answer the question about precision of numpy.sin(x)? I provided information about the purpose purely for context.

Comment: "precise" as in floating point precision?

Comment: also, i don't understand your code block as the `while` condition would never be met

Comment: If that's your plan, then don't worry. `numpy.sin` will be way more accurate than what you'll get with your `increment`. What you're doing is basically a grid search. Have a look instead at well-tested and well-implemented existing solutions like this one: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html

Comment: @PaulH sorry about the while block, it was a typo. Yes, I am talking about floating point precision.

Comment: well, numpy has 64-bit floats.

Comment: Since you are evaluating it at scalars, use `math.sin`.

Comment: @Lagerbaer fsolve() is no good because it also just gives me the first solution. The idea is precisely to make the increment as precise as possible, but using machine epsilon just takes too much time.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not evaluating it at scalars?

Comment: What's `x`?  A single number, a list or an array?  `np.sin(anArray)`, `math.sin(aNumber)`.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, yes it's a scalar, but numpy.sin() works fine with scalars. I don't see the issue nor its relevance.

Comment: @PaulH well, to be pedantic, `numpy` supports various floating point types. It could be float16, float32, and float64 (half, single, and double precision). It even supports [extended precision](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision) floats, but IIRC, all that is pretty sketchy

Comment: It's more a matter of speed. Precision is probably the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know that. since its extended precision floats are sketchy, i recommended 64-bit floats as "the most precise".

Answer (score 7):

## The answer

`np.sin` will in general be as precise as possible, given the precision of the `double` (ie 64-bit `float`) variables in which the input, output, and intermediate values are stored. You can get a reasonable measure of the precision of `np.sin` by comparing it to the arbitrary precision version of `sin` from `mpmath`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpmath
from mpmath import mp

# set mpmath to an extremely high precision
mp.dps = 100
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, num=int(1e3))

# numpy sine values
y = np.sin(x)

# extremely high precision sine values
realy = np.array([mpmath.sin(a) for a in x])

# the end results are arrays of arbitrary precision mpf values (ie abserr.dtype=='O')
diff = realy - y
abserr = np.abs(diff)
relerr = np.abs(diff/realy)

plt.plot(x, abserr, lw=.5, label='Absolute error')
plt.plot(x, relerr, lw=.5, label='Relative error')
plt.axhline(2e-16, c='k', ls='--', lw=.5, label=r'$2 \cdot 10^{-16}$')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlim(-np.pi, np.pi)
plt.ylim(1e-20, 1e-15)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('Error in np.sin(x)')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Thus, it is reasonable to say that both the relative and absolute errors of `np.sin` have an upper bound of `2e-16`.

## A better answer

There's an excellent chance that if you make `increment` small enough for your approach to be accurate, your algorithm will be too slow for practical use. The standard equation solving approaches won't work for you, since you don't have a standard function. Instead, you have an implicit, multi-valued function. Here's a stab at a general purpose approach for getting all solutions to this kind of equation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as spo

eps = 1e-4

def func(x, a):
    return a*np.sin(x) - x

def uniqueflt(arr):
    b = arr.copy()
    b.sort()
    d = np.append(True, np.diff(b))
    return b[d>eps]

initial_guess = np.arange(-9, 9) + eps
# uniqueflt removes any repeated roots
roots = uniqueflt(spo.fsolve(func, initial_guess, args=(10,)))
# roots is an array with the 7 unique roots of 10*np.sin(x) - x == 0:
#     array([-8.42320394e+00, -7.06817437e+00, -2.85234190e+00, -8.13413225e-09,
#            2.85234189e+00,  7.06817436e+00,  8.42320394e+00])

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, num=int(1e3))
plt.plot(x, x, label=r'$y = x$')
plt.plot(x, 10*np.sin(x), label=r'$y = 10 \cdot sin(x)$')
plt.plot(roots, 10*np.sin(roots), '.', c='k', ms=7, label='Solutions')

plt.ylim(-10.5, 20)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

You'll have to tweak the `initial_guess` depending on your value of `a`. `initial_guess` has to be at least as large as the actual number of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

The accuracy of the sine function is not so relevant here, you'd better perform the study of the equation.

If you write it in the form `sin x / x = sinc x = 1 / a`, you immediately see that the number of solutions is the number of intersections of the cardinal sine with an horizontal. This number depends on the ordinates of the extrema of the latter.

The extrema are found where `x cos x - sin x = 0` or `x = tan x`, and the corresponding values are `cos x`. This is again a transcendental equation, but it is parameterless and you can solve it once for all. Also note that for increasing values of x, the solutions get closer and closer to `(k+1/2)π`.

Now for a given value of `1 / a`, you can find all the extrema below and above and this will give you starting intervals where to look for the roots. The secant method will be handy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to estimate the accuracy of `sin()` AND `cos()` for a given argument `x` would be:

```
eps_trig = np.abs(1 - (np.sin(x)**2 + np.cos(x)**2)) / 2
```

You may want to drop last `2` just to be on the "safe side" (well, there are values of `x` for which this approximation does not hold very well, in particular for `x` close to `-90 deg`). I would suggest to test at around `x=pi/4`

#### Explanation:

The basic idea behind this approach is as follows... Let's say our `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` deviates from exact values by *a single* "error value" `eps`. That is, `exact_sin(x) = sin(x) + eps` (same for `cos(x)`). Also, let's call `delta` to be the measured deviation from the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity):

```
delta = 1 - sin(x)**2 - cos(x)**2
```

For exact functions, `delta` should be zero:

```
1 - exact_sin(x)**2 - exact_cos(x)**2 == 0
```

or, going to inexact functions:

```
1 - (sin(x) + eps)**2 - (cos(x) + eps)**2 == 0 =>
1 - sin(x)**2 - cos(x)**2 = delta = 2*eps*(sin(x) + cos(x)) + 2*eps**2
```

Neglecting last term `2*eps**2` (assume small errors):

```
2*eps*(sin(x)+cos(x)) = 1 - sin(x)**2 - cos(x)**2
```

If we choose `x` such that `sin(x)+cos(x)` hovers around 1 (or, somewhere in the range `0.5-2`), we can roughly estimate that `eps = |1 - sin(x)**2 - cos(x)**2|/2`.

Comment: Neat idea. Two questions: what's the factor of `2**-.5` for? And how would you use this to determine the error in `np.sin` by itself?

Comment: @tel One cannot use this approach to  estimate the error of `sin()` itself (or "alone") it is a mixture of _both_ `sin(x)` *AND* `cos(x)`. The `sqrt(2)` was a mistake (when I was experimenting I had simply `2` but when I was typing here I was thinking about something else).

Comment: I still don't get what the `2` in the denominator is for. Aren't you just trying to measure deviations from the Pythagorean identity (ie `sin**2 + cos**2 - 1 == 0`)? Or is the idea to measure the roughly half of the error due to each of `sin**2` and `cos**2`?

Comment: @tel, thanks for edit: I forgot to write `2` in front of `eps**2`.

Comment: The explanation makes your approach much clearer, thanks. Given that your assumptions hold reasonably well, it does seem like it would be valid to assume that `eps` is the absolute error in `sin` (and `cos` as well). However, I can confirm that the absolute error in both `np.sin` and `np.cos` dip way down at their respective nodes, so you probably can't get away with assuming `eps_sin==eps_cos`.

Answer (score 2):

To the precision you already got good answers. To the task itself, you can be faster by investing some calculus.

- First, from the bounds of the sine you know that any solution must be in the interval `[-abs(a),abs(a)]`. If `abs(a)\le 1` then the only root in `[-1,1]` is `x=0`
- Apart from the interval containing zero, you also know that there is exactly one root in any of the intervals between the roots of `cos(x)=1/a` which are the extrema of `a*sin(x)-x`. Set `phi=arccos(1/a) in [0,pi]`, then these roots are `-phi+2*k*pi` and `phi+2*k*pi`.
- The interval for `k=0` might contain 3 roots if `1<a<0.5*pi`. For the positive root one knows `x/a=sin(x)>x-x^3/6` so that `x^2>6-6/a`.
- And lastly, the problem is symmetric, if `x` is a root, so is `-x` so all you have to do is find the positive roots.

So to compute the roots,

- Start the root list with the root `0`.
- in the case `abs(a)<=1`, there are no further roots, return. One could also use `-pi/2<=a<=1`.
- in the case `1<a<pi/2`, apply the chosen bracketing method to the interval `[sqrt(6-6/a), pi/2]`, add the root to the list, and return.
- In the remaining cases where `abs(a)>=0.5*pi`:

  - Compute `phi=arccos(1/a)`.
  - Then for any positive integer `k` apply the bracketing method to the intervals [2*(k-1)*pi+phi,2*k*pi-phi] and [2*k*pi-phi,2*k*pi-phi so that `(k-0.5)*pi < abs(a)`  `[(k-0.5)*pi, (k+0.5)*pi]` as long as the lower interval boundary is smaller than `abs(a)` and the function has a sign change over the interval.
  - Add the root found to the list. Return with the list after the loop ends.

```js
let a=10;

function f(x) { return x - a * Math.sin(x); }

findRoots();

//-------------------------------------------------

function findRoots() {
    log.innerHTML = `<p>roots for parameter a=${a}`;
    rootList.innerHTML = "<tr><th>root <i>x</i></th><th><i>x-a*sin(x)</i></th><th>numSteps</th></tr>";
    rootList.innerHTML += "<tr><td>0.0<td>0.0<td>0</tr>";

    if( Math.abs(a)<=1) return;

    if( (1.0<a) && (a < 0.5*Math.PI) ) {
        illinois(Math.sqrt(6-6/a), 0.5*Math.PI);
        return;
    }

    const phi = Math.acos(1.0/a);
    log.innerHTML += `phi=${phi}<br>`;
    let right = 2*Math.PI-phi;
    for (let k=1; right<Math.abs(a); k++) { 
        let left = right;
        right = (k+2)*Math.PI + ((0==k%2)?(-phi):(phi-Math.PI));
        illinois(left, right);
    }
}

function illinois(a, b) {
  log.innerHTML += `<p>regula falsi variant illinois called for interval [a,b]=[${a}, ${b}]`;
  let fa = f(a);
  let fb = f(b);
  let numSteps=2;
  log.innerHTML += ` values f(a)=${fa}, f(b)=${fb}</p>`;

  if (fa*fb > 0) return;

  if (Math.abs(fa) < Math.abs(fb)) { var h=a; a=b; b=h; h=fa; fa=fb; fb=h;}
  
  while(Math.abs(b-a) > 1e-15*Math.abs(b)) {
    let c = b - fb*(b-a)/(fb-fa);
    let fc = f(c); numSteps++;
    log.innerHTML += `step ${numSteps}: midpoint c=${c}, f(c)=${fc}<br>`;

    if ( fa*fc < 0 ) {
      fa *= 0.5;
    } else {
      a = b; fa = fb;
    }
    b = c; fb = fc;
  }
  rootList.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${b}<td>${fb}<td>${numSteps}</tr>`;
}

aInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let a_new = Number.parseFloat(aInput.value);
  if( isNaN(a_new) ) {
      alert('Not a number '+aInput.value);
  } else if(a!=a_new) {
     a = a_new;
     findRoots();
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Factor <i>a</i>: <input id="aInput" value="10" /></p>
<h3>Root list</h3>
<table id="rootList" border = 1>
</table>
<h3>Computation log</h3>
<div id="log"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be precise up to [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon)

```
>>> from numpy import sin as sin_np
>>> from math import sin as sin_math
>>> x = 0.0
>>> sin_np(x) - x
0.0
>>> sin_math(x) - x
0.0
>>>
```

You could consider using `scipy.optimize` for this problem:

```
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize
>>> from math import sin
>>> a = 1.0
```

Then define your objective as so:

```
>>> def obj(x):
...     return abs(x - a*sin(x))
...
```

And you can go ahead and solve this problem numerically by:

```
>>> sol = minimize(obj, 0.0)
>>> sol
      fun: array([ 0.])
 hess_inv: array([[1]])
      jac: array([ 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 3
      nit: 0
     njev: 1
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 0.])
```

Now lets try with a new value of a

```
>>> a = .5
>>> sol = minimize(obj, 0.0)
>>> sol
      fun: array([ 0.])
 hess_inv: array([[1]])
      jac: array([ 0.5])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 315
      nit: 0
     njev: 101
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([ 0.])
>>>
```

In case you want to find a non-trivial solution to this problem, you need to change `x0` iteratively to values greater than zero and also lesser than. Also, manage the bounds of `x` in minimise by setting `bounds` in scipy.optimize.minimize, you would be able to walk from -infty to +infty ( or very large numbers ).

Comment: the problem is that I get 1 solution, for larger a, say ~1000, I should expect ~100 solutions

Comment: The only solution for this problem is `n*pi`, n=0 or x=0

Comment: no it's not, draw it if you don't believe me, geogebra has a nice online edition. $a$ is a constant of arbitrary value, it's just 1 in my code because it has to be /some/ number.

Comment: Do you mean then a solution for `y = a sin(x)` where `y=0.0` and then you have so many solutions i.e. `x = n*pi` where `n=0 to infinity`. If it is `x = a * sin(x)` then `x - a sin(x) = 0.0` the only real solution is 0.0.

Comment: I am not going to respond to you anymore since you're obviously trolling

Comment: I understand from the picture what you are looking for. See edit. :) I see you were trying to find a non-trivial solution to this problem. It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: thanks for the edit, but I completely don't get how to properly set these bounds. I pass the edges of an interval as bounds=[low,high], but I keep getting a ValueError: length of x0 != length of bounds error

Comment: Can you share the call to minimize ?

Comment: I managed to make it work, but it gives wrong results; ie. it "finds" roots it had already founded . say, for scipy.optimize.minimize(f, 4*eps, bounds=[(4*eps,10)]) it gives result 8.8817842e-16 even though it had already found the root 0. .